# How to create daily backup with unique name in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to make full database backup of my server's all databases with unique name daily. For that I have an idea to keep timestamp which will make database copy separate.
Suppose there is a database on server named ABCD then it should be backuped like:

```
ABCD_21_03_2013
ABCD_22_03_2013
```

How can I do this. I don't know much about these types of SQL Backup JOBS.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23601/how-to-automatically-regularly-a-week-backup-sql-server-database-if-changes-exis

Comment: You may Help this with **auto backup shedule**
http://stackoverflow.com/a/43245169/6863414

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Automatic backup of all databases on the server.***

**About Jobs:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx

**Query:**

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE 
      @FileName NVARCHAR(1024)
    , @DBName NVARCHAR(256)
    , @PathName NVARCHAR(256)
    , @Message NVARCHAR(2048)
    , @IsCompressed BIT

SELECT 
      @PathName = 'D:\BACKUP\'
    , @IsCompressed = 1 

DECLARE db CURSOR LOCAL READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD FOR  
    SELECT
          sd.name
        , file_path = @PathName + FileDate + '_' + name + '.bak'
    FROM sys.databases sd
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT FileDate = 'ABCD_' + REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103), '/', '_')
    ) fd
    WHERE sd.state_desc != 'OFFLINE'
        AND sd.name NOT IN ('master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb')
    ORDER BY sd.name 

OPEN db

FETCH NEXT FROM db INTO 
      @DBName
    , @FileName  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN 

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @Message = REPLICATE('-', 80) + CHAR(13) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 120) + N': ' + @DBName
    RAISERROR (@Message, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT

    SELECT @SQL = 
    'BACKUP DATABASE [' + @DBName + ']
    TO DISK = N''' + @FileName + '''
    WITH FORMAT, ' + CASE WHEN @IsCompressed = 1 THEN N'COMPRESSION, ' ELSE '' END + N'INIT, STATS = 15;' 

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

    FETCH NEXT FROM db INTO 
          @DBName
        , @FileName 

END   

CLOSE db   
DEALLOCATE db
```

**Output:**

```
BACKUP DATABASE [AdventureWorks2008R2]
    TO DISK = N'D:\BACKUP\ABCD_24_05_2013_AdventureWorks2008R2.bak'
    WITH FORMAT, COMPRESSION, INIT, STATS = 15;

BACKUP DATABASE [AdventureWorks2008R2_Live]
    TO DISK = N'D:\BACKUP\ABCD_24_05_2013_AdventureWorks2008R2_Live.bak'
    WITH FORMAT, COMPRESSION, INIT, STATS = 15;

BACKUP DATABASE [AdventureWorks2012]
    TO DISK = N'D:\BACKUP\ABCD_24_05_2013_AdventureWorks2012.bak'
    WITH FORMAT, COMPRESSION, INIT, STATS = 15;
```

**Results:**

```
2013-05-24 09:54:34: AdventureWorks2008R2
15 percent processed.
30 percent processed.
45 percent processed.
60 percent processed.
75 percent processed.
90 percent processed.
Processed 23416 pages for database 'AdventureWorks2008R2', file 'AdventureWorks2008R2_Data' on file 1.
Processed 1 pages for database 'AdventureWorks2008R2', file 'AdventureWorks2008R2_Log' on file 1.
BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 23417 pages in 4.052 seconds (45.148 MB/sec).

.....
```

Answer (score 26):

To create a daily backup with a name such as Filename_MM_DD_YYYY:

1. In SSMS, right-click the database you want to backup
2. Select Tasks | Back Up
3. In the dialog, select the type and location of the backup
4. At the top of this dialog, select the **Script Action to Job** option in the **Script** drop down menu
5. A **New Job** dialog is opened and the first step creates a database backup
   Go to the fist step and click **Edit**

Existing code looks like:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [AdventureWorks2012] TO  DISK = N'E:\Test\AdventureWorks.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'AdventureWorks2012-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

Replace it to be

```
DECLARE @SQLStatement VARCHAR(2000) 
SET @SQLStatement = 'E:\Test\AdventureWorks_' + CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 110) +'.bak' 
BACKUP DATABASE [AdventureWorks2012] TO  DISK = @SQLStatement
```

6 Save the job

The database backups will be named:

AdventureWorks_07-29-2013

AdventureWorks_07-30-2013

AdventureWorks_07-31-2013

Now all you have to do is make the right schedule

Answer (score 2):

I think, best way to perform schedule back-up is to create `Job`. Add your back-up job and schedule that on particular date and time.

[How to create job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Some third-party backup programs, for example: [EMS SQL Backup](http://www.sqlmanager.net/products/mssql/sqlbackup/), allow setting templates for backup file names. Timestamp, server instance name, database names and other info can be added to file name.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the posts
I just want to share a small update I have made on the script to make log database backups and automatically skip all databases with `recovery model = simple` which does not allow log backups. Hope it helps...
And yes, Mr. Ravi is right the best approach is to create a job, I've created a SP and am running from a job.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_logbackup 
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE 
  @FileName NVARCHAR(1024)
, @DBName NVARCHAR(256)
, @PathName NVARCHAR(256)
, @Message NVARCHAR(2048)
, @IsCompressed BIT
SELECT 
  @PathName = '\\myServer\...' 
, @IsCompressed = 1 
DECLARE db CURSOR LOCAL READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD FOR  
SELECT
      sd.name
    , file_path = @PathName + name + '_' + FileDate + '.trn'
FROM sys.databases sd
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT FileDate = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(), 20),'-','_'),':',''),' ','') 
) fd
WHERE sd.state_desc != 'OFFLINE'
    AND sd.recovery_model != 3
    AND sd.name NOT IN ('master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb')
ORDER BY sd.name 
OPEN db
FETCH NEXT FROM db INTO 
  @DBName
, @FileName  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN 
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @Message = REPLICATE('-', 80) + CHAR(13) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 120) + N': ' + @DBName
RAISERROR (@Message, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT

SELECT @SQL = 
'BACKUP LOG [' + @DBName + ']
TO DISK = N''' + @FileName + '''
WITH FORMAT, NAME = N''' + @DBName + ''', SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10;' 

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
FETCH NEXT FROM db INTO 
      @DBName
    , @FileName 
END   
CLOSE db   
DEALLOCATE db
```